# Help explaining sum notation

Tags: summation

So, I have the question and I also have the answer. 
Need to prove:
[image]

And here is the answer

[image]

Can you please explain the steps. They are in the second picture but I do not understand where they are coming from.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since $\bar{X}$ is a constant, adding a constant $n$ times is the same as multiplying a constant by $n$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition it is $\overline X=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Now you can multiply both sides by n. $\overline X$ is the arithmetic mean of the $X_i´s$.

And here  $\sum_{i=1}^n \overline X$ you can factor out $\overline X$, because $\overline X$ is not indexed. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n \overline X=\overline X \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n 1$. And $\sum_{i=1}^n 1=n$. Thus $\sum_{i=1}^n \overline X=n\cdot \overline X$

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like $\bar{X}$ does not depend on $i$, hence $\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X} = \bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n\bar{X}$.

As for why $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = n \bar{X}$, there's not enough information in your post to be able to address that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, $\bar{X}$ is referring to the arithmetic mean of a set $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}$  Now, since the arithmetic mean is defined as 
$$\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}=\bar{X}$$ it is equivalent to say that 
$$X_1+X_2+...+X_n=n\bar{X}$$
and then of course using summation notation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}=n\bar{X}$$
Since the arithmetic mean of a number is just a constant, if I add up $\bar{X}$ n times it is the same as multiplying $\bar{X}$ by $n$.  This gives me
$$\bar{X}+\bar{X}+...+\bar{X}=n\bar{X}$$ and then of course using summation notation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\bar{X}}=n\bar{X}$$Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{(X_i-\bar{X})}=(X_1-\bar{X})+(X_2-\bar{X})+...+(X_n-\bar{X})$$
rearranging by commutativity
$$=X_1+X_2+...+X_n-\bar{X}-\bar{X}-...-\bar{X}$$
$$=(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)-(\bar{X}+\bar{X}+...+\bar{X})$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}-\sum_{i=1}^n{\bar{X}}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}-n\bar{X}$$
$$n\bar{X}-n\bar{X}$$
$$=0$$

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean!! I was confused at first but they literally just equal each other, through other properties. Thank you so much!